# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings - Codazon Themeframework -- Categoriestree.php

Tags: php, magento-1.9

After migrating a Magento 1.9.3.7 site between servers I am unable to access the settings page: Navigate to Admin> System> Configuration
The following error is displayed:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/defaultwebsite/public/app/code/local/Codazon/Themeframework/Model/System/Config/Source/Categoriestree.php:28

Categoriestree.php:28 error here >>

```
$this->_categoriesTree[] = array('value' => $item['category_id'],'label' => str_repeat("–––", $level)." ".$item['name']);
```

Comment: Files we.tl/t-ZRCirZ7wik

Comment: Please embed the relevant code to your post. The link may become absolute and then others won't be able to use your question + answers.

Comment: Server Log:  AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/defaultwebsite/public/app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this post helps , similar to your problem error
https://www.key2goal.com/article/wordpress-error-php-71-php-fatal-error-uncaught-error-operator-not-supported-strings

If you using php 7.1, then you need proper array define..

May be define like this

```
$this->_categoriesTree = array();
```